# Why are most of my CSS files not loading when using an ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Only some of my styles are loading and I'm not sure why. The stylesheet must work if some of my styling is working, but why aren't *all* of them loading? I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

I have the following in every HTML file I will be using.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">
```

I don't think that it's the file path because *some* of the styles show, just not all.

Comment: you'll want to add more details here... if it's all on a particular .css file check paths.  (if all comes from layout template, check that file) Otherwise the browser's inspector/dev tools will tell you a lot about any particular element.  (right-click choose "inspect")  This will show you all the styles that apply to that element and which have been overriden (shows as cross-out) Remember that style rules cascade.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Sometimes you have to do a shift + reload to update the css styles.